# Cancel request processing when user stopped page loading

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have an action in my Aspnet 5 (Aspnet Core) WebAPI controller, which while being requested may take a lot of time and it will runs to the end even if user has canceled loading. Is there any variant of cancellation token for requests in aspnet or any event in conroller/httpContext, which can help me to stop action when user already does not need its results?

If use cancellationToken, it never changes its state:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<string> Get(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) ;
        return;
    });
    return "hi";
}
```

, also callback passed to token's Register method never called too.

Comment: it looks impossible to cancel the token from client side

Comment: @KhanhTO, I think server has to change token's state when tcp connection aborted and surely I dont expect from client any tokens to be passed.

Answer (score 0):

there is no reliable event to handle browser load stop. IE has `document.onstop` event,other browsers wont support it.

maybe you can try something like ,placing your ajax calls in `window.onload` event.
onload event fires after completely loading the DOM and other resources used in page.

so if a user stops page load before completely loading,`window.onload` event wont get fired and as a result your ajax calls wont get executed.

Comment: I have no browser on client side, just http rest client, which can break connection.

Comment: ok then,you have to look into [this](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/07/19/cancelling-long-running-queries-in-asp-net-mvc-and-web-api.aspx)

Comment: unfortunately, for some reason cancellationToken never changes it state or signals about request cancellation